# how to make sure that the public facing sharepoint site is secure?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

How to make sure that my public site which is built on SharePoint 2010 is secure ?

- Is there any tool is available who check site vulnerabilities ? Any
  test cases or methods to check the site security?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some nice tips given in this article http://blog.furuknap.net/want-to-use-sharepoint-as-your-public-web-site-make-sure-you-know-what-you-are-doing as well I suggest you to have a look at the solutions provided by AvePoint (www.avepoint.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, the best way to test for everything is to do unit testing, and test every possible combination of possible vulnerabilities you can think of.  You can either script this, or do it manually.

The best approach would probably be to create users, each with a unique permission level, and try to access sites or pages that they shouldn't.  If they can, then that's a vulnerability.

Another one to look out for is query strings in the URL.  If you have a page with list items, and you only want people to access their own items, for example, make sure they can't just connect to the page directly.

There are hundreds of possible ways to attack a site, more than I can fit in this answer, you just have to think of every possible flaw, and attempt it on your site.

If you are looking for various tools to do it for you, however, [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cfdbf4e7-83d2-43b9-9aaa-6379cbad1cb0/sharepoint-security-testing-tools?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) is a link that should help you as well.

Comment: Your very welcome :)

Comment: A quick question, I got a site which I have to check as security point of view.

Comment: A quick question, I got a site which I have to check from security point of view. Please share some scenarios for security test. I've figured out: 1) simple URL access to the list view 2) access to the web service model through code 3) check with different user rights. I know its a bit late I should ask this question prior to my current question :(

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to make sure:

- No Anonymous access
- Use SSL
- Use Claim based or Form Based authentication
- Use Unqiue permissions
- Use groups to manage the permissions
- make sure all authenticated user group not added any where
- enable the auditing on the Site
- make sure your sharePoint farm is upto date for security vulnerabilities(MSFT release every month).
- reduce the number of site collections admins.